# Extrapolation of linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So, assuming that I had two linear transformations $\mathbb{R^n}$ -> $\mathbb{R^m}$, *P* and *K*, and there are *n* linearly independent vectors *v* for which *P(v)* = *K(v)*, does *P(v)* = *K(v)* for all vectors *v*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since any vector in $\Bbb R^n$ is a linear combination of the $n$ linearly independent vectors $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ i.e. $v=\sum_i c_iv_i$, the image of $v$ under $P,K$ is a linear combination of the images of $v_i$, i.e. $P(v)=\sum_i c_iP(v_i)=\sum_i c_iK(v_i)=K(v)$.